# MS SQL syntax SET vs. SELECT

Tags: sql-server, variable-assignment

I'm trying to follow the following SQL Query (Partial code):

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)       -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256)      -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256)  -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20)   -- used for file name 

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'
SET @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT name 
    FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
```

My questions:

1. Why is `@path` using `SET`, while `@fileDate` using `SELECT`?
2. Why isn't `@fileDate` `SET` as well?

Comment: Well it's your code, shouldn't you know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a backup query

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\' --- It means we are taking backup on a static path

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) --- filedate will be dynamic due to getdate() and it may be used in the .bak file naming convention so thats why mostly we use select for @filedate

e.g. if performing a backup daily once.

then it may provide the backup on static path (@path) and backup with naming convention e.g. ____bkup_20160519.bak

here 20160519 is @filedate which will change daily

Let me know if you need more idea regarding it.

Comment: So that is what I am thinking??? SET assigns static value whereas SELECT requires SQL to calculate the value?

Answer (score 0):

In your exmaple either Set or Select is same.
Select is used to selected values to more than one variable like shown below

This works

```
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ,@path = 'C:\Backup\'
```

but this does not work

```
set @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ,@path = 'C:\Backup\'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I do not see a reason.  One reason I would use Select over Set if I want to set multiple values at once.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

--SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'  

Select  @path = 'C:\Backup\' , @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

Select @Path, @FileDate
```